# BASH: getopts with default parameters value

Tags: bash, parameters, default, getopts

I've got another bash-script problem I simply couldn't solve. It's my simplified script showing the problem:

```
while getopts "r:" opt; do
case $opt in

  r)
    fold=/dev
    dir=${2:-fold}

     a=`find $dir -type b | wc -l`
     echo "$a"
  ;;
esac
done
```

I calling it by:

```
  ./sc.sh -r /bin
```

and it's work, but when I don't give a parameter it doesn't work:

```
  ./sc.sh -r
```

I want /dev to be my default parameter $2 in this script.

Answer (score 3):

There may be other parameters before, don't hard-code the parameter number ($2).

The getopts help says

> When an option requires an argument,    getopts places that argument into the shell variable OPTARG.
>   ...
>   [In silent error reporting mode,] if a
>       required argument is not found, getopts places a ':' into NAME and
>       sets OPTARG to the option character found.

So you want:

```
dir=/dev                            # the default value
while getopts ":r:" opt; do         # note the leading colon
    case $opt in
        r) dir=${OPTARG} ;;
        :) if [[ $OPTARG == "r" ]]; then
               # -r with required argument missing.
               # we already have a default "dir" value, so ignore this error
               :
           fi
           ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

a=$(find "$dir" -type b | wc -l)
echo "$a"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "r" opt; do
case $opt in

  r)
    fold=/dev
    dir=${2:-$fold}

     echo "asdasd"
  ;;
esac
done
```

Remove the colon (`:`) in the getopts argument. This caused getopt to expect an argument. (see [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) for more information about getopt)

Comment: I tried this before. Still doesn't work when I calling it without parameter: ./sc.sh -r /// error: ./sc.sh: option requires an argument -- r

Comment: Could you please help me with the same problem but with conditional statement "if". It's also return an error. The code looks like this: 
if [ $1 != -r ]; then

fold=/dev
dir=${1:-$fold}

a=`find $dir -type b | wc -l`

echo "$a"

fi

Comment: Ok, I just got this ([[ $1 != -r ]])! Don't bother then and thanks in advance for your help.