# Getopts same flag two times

Tags: bash, shell, printing, getopts

Hi i have a basic question but i wasn't able to find a good answer

I have this Code:

```
while getopts :weco:r:u:hP: ARG; do
  case $ARG in
             .
             .
             .

    h)  #set option "h" - show help;
      help
      ;;
    P)  #set option "P" - select Printer;
      PRINTER=$OPTARG
      ;;
    \?) #unrecognized option - show help
      echo -e \\n"Option not recognized."
      help
      ;;
  esac
done
```

And now i want to use "-P" twice, if you use "-P PRINTER" it uses the given Printer but if you just use "-P" it uses a default value read out of a file.

Can i manage it like that? Sorry if that's the correct answer, i cant test it right now.

```
while getopts :weco:r:u:hP:P ARG; do
  case $ARG in
             .
             .
             .

    h)  #set option "h" - show help;
      help
      ;;
    P)  #set option to use default
      PRINTER=BLAFOO
    P)  #set option "P" - select Printer;
      PRINTER=$OPTARG
      ;;
    \?) #unrecognized option - show help
      echo -e \\n"Option not recognized."
      help
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I think that this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709328/2088135 - you can set the default either before the `getopts` loop or inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you re-write your own argument parser, since `getopts` doesn't support what you want.

```
while true; do
  case $1 in
    -h)  #set option "h" - show help;
      echo help
      shift
      ;;
    -P)  #set option "P" - select Printer;
      shift
      case $1 in
      ""|-*)
        PRINTER=BLAFOO
        ;;
      *)
        PRINTER=$1
        shift
        ;;
      esac
      # echo PRINTER=$PRINTER
      ;;
    -*|*)  #unrecognized option - show help
      echo -e \\n"Option not recognized."
      echo help
      break ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: @Nico, does is work for you? Please give some feedback if you can.