# Bash getopt check parameter for every single user in system

Tags: bash, getopts

Ive done a script which works as follows

```
bash users.sh -u "user" [-f | -d | -g]
```

1. -f , shows the number of files of the specified user directory.
2. -d, shows the number of folders of the specified user directory.
3. -g , shows the groups to which the specified user belongs.

---

```
 #!/bin/bash

user="" ;
directory="" ; 

    while getopts u:fgd options; do
        case "$options" in
        u)
        if grep -q "^$OPTARG" /etc/passwd ; then
        user="$OPTARG";
          echo "user existe";
        else
              echo "user no existe"
            fi
        ;;
        g)
        if [ -n "$user" ] ; then
              echo "los grupos del usuario son: ";
              groups "$user" ;
        else
              echo "user missing"
            fi
        ;;
        d)
        if [ -n "$user" ] ; then
          directory=$(grep $user /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 6);
          directory+=/*/;
          echo "numero de carpetas";
          ls -d $directory | wc -l
        else
              echo "user missing"
            fi
        ;;
        f) 
        if [ -n "$user" ] ; then
          directory=$(grep $user /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 6);
          echo "numero de archivos";
          ls -p $directory | grep -v /  | wc -l
        else
              echo "user missing"
            fi
        ;;
        *) echo "opcion invalida $options" ;;
        esac

    done
```

The point is that my current script "must" include an user as an arguemnt. But I would want that if the username argument is missing

```
bash users.sh -u [-f | -d | -g]
```

It would show the specified option for each user of the system instead of a specific user

Comment: This looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55751436/bash-getopts-how-to-make-2-mandatory-arguments-being-the-second-one-eligible-a Are you in the same class?

Comment: Don't run `grep` in the `getopts` loop. Set variables from each option, and run it after the loop with appropriate parameters. If the `user` variable isn't set, process the entire file instead of using `grep`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BASH: getopts with default parameters value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708565/bash-getopts-with-default-parameters-value)